# ¿Como extraer un campo especifico de una web ajena y cargarla desde la URL?

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Hola que tal mi consulta es la siguiente:
Hay una web de envio de paquetes que tiene su propio seguimiento. El problema es que no tiene ningun estilo CSS y es en HTML puro, dando un texto por default en una pestaña toda en blanco.

Ver ejemplo aqui:
https://sistema.mdcargas.com/vertracking.php?guia=R-586-62892&empresa=MDCARGAS

Mi idea es crear una web a la cual ingresando el URL del seguimiento, tome el contenido de ese URL (En este caso lo que hay dentro del `<body>`) lo copie y la muestre en la mia, asi puedo darle estilos con CSS y hacerlo mas agradable a la vista.
Lo ideal seria que al escribir la URL de mi web, pueda agregar el link ahi mismo y me muestre el resultado sin necesidad de cargar mi pagina primero y luego y pegar el link para que se genere el texto.

Guardaria "R-586-62892" en una variable llamada `codigoPaquete` para agregarla a otra variable llamada `linkPaquete` que contenga

```
https://sistema.mdcargas.com/vertracking.phpguia=${codigoPaquete}empresa=MDCARGAS
```

Ejemplo: https://miweb.com/R-586-62892

No busco un código que me de la solucion sino una guía de por donde tengo que investigar mas para llegar a ese resultado.
Tengo un conocimiento muy basico de Javascript y no se por donde debería arrancar como para que al menos tenga esa funcionalidad.
Desde ya muchas gracias por tomarse el tiempo de leer esto.

Comment: buenos días, tu pregunta no se acomoda a las políticas de stackoverflow, para obtener los datos es necesario que disponga de un API REST de la pagina que traiga los datos en este caso deber utilizar XML y JSON, para eso deber habla con el administrado de la pagina para habilitar un ***API REST*** e investigué sobre este tema

Comment: Esa página no tiene HTML, solo muestra el mensaje. Puedes obtener el mensaje usando la [API fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) y lo agregas a tu web como prefieras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usualmente, dado que quisieras meter el estado de la guía en un contenedor del tipo

```
 <div class="estilo_bonito" id="estado_guia"></div>
```

Obtendrías el texto de la respuesta mediante algo como

```
async function obtenerGuia(codigoGuia) {
   const respuesta = await fetch(`https://sistema.mdcargas.com/vertracking.php?guia=${codigoGuia}&empresa=MDCARGAS`)

   let contenido=await respuesta.text(),
       contenedor=document.querySelector('#estado_guia')
  
   contenedor.innerText=contenido
}
```

Pero si haces eso verás que el sitio no devuelve las cabeceras necesarias para hacer una [petición cross-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) y salta una excepción:

> Access to fetch at 'https://sistema.mdcargas.com/...'  from origin '' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

La solución sería hacer la petición del lado del servidor o pasar por un proxy que modifique la respuesta añadiendo las cabeceras necesarias.

---

**Hallazgo**

Por curiosidad me metí al sitio público: https://mdcargas.com/, donde tienen un formulario para hacer tracking:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si inspeccionas la petición en Chrome devtools, verás que el formulario manda una petición GET a

```
https://mdcargas000.gear.host/api.php?tipo=R&suc=586&numero=62892
```

Cuya respuesta es un json de la forma:

```
{ estado: "El envio R-586-62892 se encuentra ENTREGADO" }
```

Y ésta sí expone la cabecera necesaria. Por lo tanto, la función antes sugerida quedaría así:

```
async function obtenerGuia(codigoGuia) {
   let [tipo,suc,numero]=codigoGuia.split('-')
   const respuesta = await fetch(`https://mdcargas000.gear.host/api.php?tipo=${tipo}&suc=${suc}&numero=${numero}`)

   contenido=await respuesta.json(),
   contenedor=document.querySelector('#estado_guia')
  
   contenedor.innerText=contenido.estado
}
```